# jQuery parse dynamic html and find text inside tag

Tags: json, parsing

I've this html output after ajax call :

```
<li data-ops="[{"tags":"black","cates":"tires"}]" class="btn-hover" draggable="true"><img src="images/tidj23.jpg"></li>
```

I try to parse the "data-ops" for get the tags, but with no results.

```
  if (event.type == 'DOMNodeInserted' ) {
          var elemIt = $jq('ul.item-list li').attr('data-ops');

          if ( elemIt.indexOf("black") >= 0 ) {
            $jq(this).addClass('black');
          }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data-ops` attribute is "[{", so not finding a value of "black" is correct. It is finding the incorrect value because the quotation marks are used for delimiting the attributes value.

You can swap either the quotation marks around the attribute or those inside the json with single quotes. This will stop the browser seeing the value differently to what you are after.

```
<li data-ops="[{'tags':'black','cates':'tires'}]" class="btn-hover" draggable="true">
```